# how to set zsh completion priorities

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, zshrc

There is a file named `foo.xy`, and `foo.xy` produces `foo.yz`.

So, is there a way to make zsh complete `foo.yz` instead of `foo.xy`?

(The priority of `foo.yz` is higher than that of `foo.xy`)

It seems `tag-order` helps, but I don't know how to write right tag-order rules.

thx.